# How can I shared LinkedIn articles on Social media (ie Facebook) with title, image and content?

Tags: linkedin-api

I write articles and posts on #linkedin but Open Graph are not implemented.
So sharing articles on Facebook is really bad looking... How can I make sure image/title and some content is available on Open Graph ?

Check this example:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fpulse%2Fcreate-partnership-leadership-julien-buratto-bry6f&locale=en_US

Thank you
Julien

PS: I've sent this request to LinkedIn support channels but told me to post here... omg!

See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fpulse%2Fcreate-partnership-leadership-julien-buratto-bry6f&locale=en_US